Spring boot custom deserialzer exception gets wrapped into MethodArgumentNotValidException
REST POST endpoint receives a base64 string in the body among other values. This body needs to be converted to a object. For that we have a custom Converter<String, CustomObject>.
We register it
public void addFormatters(FormatRegistry registry){
     registry.addCOnverter(new CustomConverter());
}

In converter
public CustomObject convert(String string){
    try{
        return handle(string);
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new CustomException("Unable to handle string", e);
    }
}

What we  would like is to get a status code 400 response with message:"Unable to handle string", but what we get is whatever MethodArgumentNotValidException message is. Also MethodArgumentNotValidException  getCause returns null so i cant even access my custom exception from there. Somewhere exception gets lost.
We also have DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver that should consturct the response, but the CustomException never reaches here, it gets swapped out before it gets here.
Anyway i can ensure that the error thrown by the COnverter reaches the client?
Also a weird thing. Everything works fine on my colleagues Mac, but nor on my windows or on another colleagues computer.
EDIT:
After extensive debugging i found what was happening. Spring internally wraps my error into COnversionFailedException whitch inturn is wrapped into TypeMismachException that is then placed inside FieldError tha is inside a collection that gets placed into MethodArgumentNotValidException.
To access mu custom exception i need to iterate over FieldErrors and check 3 layers deep to see if it was my exception or not.
for(FieldError fe: exception.getFieldErrors()){
    if(fieldError.unwrap(ConversionFailedException.class).getCause() instanceof CustomException){
        handleCustomException(...);
    }
}

This works, but i dont like the solution as it makes too many assumptions on the structure of the exception. Isnt there a better way to do this?

Does this answer your question? Handling exception in Spring Boot REST thrown from custom converter

@Marc does not work for me. MethodArgumentNotValidException getCause returns null. Also previous devs have created extensive error handling based on DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  so rewriting it all over to ControllerAdvice might not be the createst idea.
